# Converting ASCII characters to UTF-8 within a Java String

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Now please read carefully since after searching much of StackOverflow it seems that my specific question has not been answered, however similar the other topic title is.

I have a string in java that is exactly as follows:

```
/Music/Robby%20Hunter%20Band%20-%20Coraz%C3%B3n.mp3
```

Now as I understand, since the object is a String it is encoded as UTF-16.  I need the String to read

```
/Music/Robby Hunter Band - Corazón.mp3
```

I've tried converting the string to an ASCII byte array and then back into a string, but that did nothing.  My guess was the byte stream was treating `%20` as 3 separate characters instead of the ASCII space character.

How can I have java read a String with ASCII characters like above and understand to convert them to their proper form?

Comment: Things like `%20` are not UTF-16 encodings.  I believe the correct term is "URL encoding".  Perhaps searching for this will give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Where is Java reading that string from, a byte stream? Then how are you reading from that byte stream? Please post your method of reading the string from the byte stream.

Comment: You need [better search terms](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+url+decode)

Comment: That other question has a perfect answer.

Comment: Ahhh thank you @kdgregory you are absolutely right. Problem solved